# How to print Time stamps through out the program in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, datetime, nsdateformatter

Some of the operations in my app are taking a lot of time to execute. SO, i am planing to print time stamps from starting of the app execution to end in order to check the time taken for certain operations. Is there any way in order to do that so that i can keep track of all the time stamps in a continuos way...

Comment: For the love of God, use Instruments!

Comment: That **is** one of the things that it was designed for!

Comment: What if you will use Instruments to find out which operation is taking how much time. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AnalysisTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewInstruments/NewFeatures42/NewFeatures42.html

Comment: Well, i would love to use instruments, but they are not as straight forward as they look and i dont wanna make things complex by using instruments.. I even tried using time profiler but the results are quiet complex and not at all useful in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You can just NSLog(@"Any sensible log message describing your location in the code") - the output in XCode contains the time it was logged, to the millisecond.

Comment: ITs not happening Matt... The output in my case just contains the classname, method name and the log statement. The time is not getting printed at all.... Any idea on this..

Answer (score 0):

You can define a var at the start of the methods you want to analyse:

```
NSTimeInterval start = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

and then print it at the end:

```
NSLog(@"It took %f seconds in method <methodname>",[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - start);
```

good luck!

Comment: i got this dude.. but i want to print the value across many classes... Any idea on that

Comment: Then you can define the var "start" as a property in you AppDelegate class and then access it from everywhere with ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).start

Comment: @AforAlpha Why? Why? WHY?! Just use instruments. If you don't know what they are - look them up! This is what they were designed for. They will do all of this for you without you having to modify any of your code! Plus you then have to remember to take all these changes out. And how do you know your extra calls to log the time taken isn't going to affect your results? USE INSTRUMENTS!

Comment: Well, i tried using time profiler. But the results are too complex to look into. I am looking for a simple and straight forward solution